# Reveal modal not firing on successful submit of form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I've been trying to figure this out and I guess it's just past my experience level.

I have a contact form built with Foundation that posts to mail.php on validated submit (handled through Foundation) and I want it to open a Reveal modal on successful submission of the form.

```
<script>
 $('#contact-form') 
.on('valid', function () {

    var fname = $("input#first-name-input").val();
    var lname = $("input#last-name-input").val();
    var email = $("input#email-input").val();
    var message = $("textarea#message-input").val();

        //Data for response
    var dataString = 'fname=' + fname +
        '&lname=' + lname +
        '&email=' + email +
        '&message=' + message;

    //Begin Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            $('#contact-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    }

}); //ajax call
return false;
});
</script>
```

In case it matters, my mail.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$msg = "

Name: $fname
Last $lname
Email: $email
Comments:
$message

";

$to = "myemail@email.com";
$subject = "mysite.com Contact";
$message = $msg;
$headers = "My site contact form";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

Any other semi-related tips would also be appreciated.

Comment: Please add error callback check it out for error first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't forget to load foundation itself in the document where modal present:

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Second, if you revealing your modal via ajax, you need to set **data-reveal-ajax="true"**:

```
<a href="http://some-url" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">
```

And finally,

```
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open', 'mail.php');
```

Comment: I was loading foundation but thanks for the reminder.
I also tried the data-reveal-ajax="true" but that didn't do the trick. I think it's your last line that I was missing. I'll try that and mark your answer if it works! Thanks!!